# Why can't I find a listed single pole dual smart switch?

Tags: code-compliance, smart-switch

I've been looking for ages for a smart switch to replace an analog single pole dual switch like [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Single-Pole-White-Compatible-with-LED-Combination-Light-Switch/1001438304?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-elc-_-google-_-lia-_-205-_-wiringdevices-_-1001438304-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&ds_a_cid=112741100&gclid=CjwKCAiA9bmABhBbEiwASb35V4YBHFOT5LCW22bHgUh8oMVlhGfczusG5x4rUFdI_cElCXjTaOOkPxoCossQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Everything I am able to find on Amazon, or really anywhere, is cheap foreign-made and not UL or ETL listed, e.g. [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZYPBYTL) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073ZVZHM4).

[This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BTBZ69B) actually claims to be ETL certified, but I bought it and it has no such marking and have not yet installed it.

But I'm just wondering if there is some fundamental issue that prevents single-pole dual smart switches from being certified? GE, Leviton, etc. make tons of smart switches but no dual ones. With there being ZERO reputable manufacturers making these, but several shady ones doing so, one has to wonder why?

Note I may just wind up getting a dual Z-wave relay and keep the switch analog, but it's not my top choice as the box is pretty cramped as it is.

**Update:**
Well I found at least [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PXRW8LD) that's cETL certified. That's progress I guess.

**Update 2:**
Wait a tick. Could [this](https://www.thesmartesthouse.com/products/zooz-z-wave-plus-s2-double-switch-zen30-white-for-light-fan-combo) actually be what I've been seeking? Z-Wave. A dimmer and a separate on/off in one gang.

**Update 3:**
The [Zooz dual switch](https://www.thesmartesthouse.com/products/zooz-z-wave-plus-s2-double-switch-zen30-white-for-light-fan-combo) arrived yesterday and indeed seems to do the trick! It has US and Canada ETL cert and looks and feels like a legitimate switch unlike the plastic garbage out there.

The dimmer part paired with my ADT Control system despite ADT not being listed as a compatible. The "relay" (for the fan) didn't pair but I assume that is because of the hub; they note that the Smartthings hub needs a special update so I'm sure it's just a software issue. It also doesn't bother me that much since turning off the lights from bed is more important than the fan which I have on 99% of the time.

One thing I don't like about it is that it doesn't have screw-in wire terminals but rather has stranded wires that come out the back that you have to pigtail to wires in the box.

But overall I'm glad to see at least one product that sortof fits the bill and hope this is a sign of things to come.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: No time to write a full proper answer, so:  It isn't that they **can't** make such a device. It is supply an demand. For a low $ device, you want to produce thousands to make certification & tooling costs pay. Far more smart switches are straight replacements of *single* switches, or are in new installs where you can use a 2-gang box for 2 switches.

Comment: Ok cool thanks! I was wondering if maybe there was a code issue with having too much going on in one pole or whatnot. I'm just surprised they're not considered popular enough to justify reputable manufacturing/listing. I personally think an elegant 2 or 3 button touch panel in a single gang would be so much more sightly than 3 gangs' worth of rockers.

Comment: Keep in mind that a **lot** of double and triple switches (including the ones I have) are for combinations such as bathroom light+fan or bathroom light+fan+heat. Those don't lend themselves as much to smart switching as things like sconces + chandelier in a fancy dining room or main lights + side lights (dimmer for when you're watching TV) in a family room.

Comment: Now what would be truly cool, and I haven't looked so it could be someone has already done it, would be a switch where the front is a small touchscreen LCD, though I guess from a practical standpoint it would be limited to 1-1/4" x 2-1/2" Decora size, which isn't terribly big - about 1/4 the size of a typical smart phone.

Comment: @PeterMoore, when you start wanting to do more complex things with smart switches like you're thinking of, you really have to let go of the notion that the relay that does the electrical switching needs to physically be in the same box as the button you use to activate it.  You can find touch screen remotes, or remotes with many physical buttons capable of controlling many remote relays, but they won't have the relays built in.  You can always add another box in your attic or something for the relays -- nothing says they have to go in an existing box.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that already exists, and it's not limited to the decora size since it replaces the faceplate as well: https://www.amazon.com/Brilliant-Control-Lighting-Switch-Version/dp/B07C6LX1NF/

Comment: Yeah this is for a 2-gang bedroom panel with a dimmer for ceiling fan lights, and a dual switch for fan motor and ceiling lights (unrelated to fan) respectively. Seems like a weird setup and I never much cared for it. @NateS very good point!

Comment: @NateS. Pretty incredible. The only catch is the price - which probably has a lot to do with volume. The tech. is basically a $ 50 smart switch + $ 100 cell phone (without the cellular connectivity) but it costs twice as much.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, agreed completely -- I think they look great, but I'm waiting for the price to drop a whole lot more before I buy any for myself.  But I do expect that to happen as they get more popular, since they really only just came out this year.

Comment: How important is native WiFi capability to you? Do you have neutral present at the switch location? Is replacing the box with a 3-gang box an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm less interested in the comm protocol and more in it being listed so it's code compliant. Neutral wire is there. Box could be replaced potentially but I think less intrusive measures exist. See my second edit above - it looks like what I want may actually exist. Ordered earlier today and will report back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I'd use Insteon for this job

The type of control flexibility you want with multiple controlled devices at a single wallstation isn't really addressed by "smart switches" *per se*, as the programming becomes involved enough that a single, standalone "smart" wallbox control with that functionality is no longer worthwhile.  Instead, what you get into at that level are *systems* of lighting control, designed for complex situations where entire sets of lights can be controlled with a single button. While there are a variety of products that can handle the duty, most require special low-voltage control wires from the wallstations to a central control unit, which rules them out in a retrofit like this.  However, the Insteon system uses a mix of power-line and wireless communications that lends itself well to retrofits, and also has a FanLinc module available for precisely the job you are after; namely, controlling a fan and its associated lights (or a different set of lights) simultaneously.

In this situation, I'd use an Insteon keypad module connected to always-hot and neutral at the wallbox, while bringing that same always-hot and neutral up to the fan.  At the fan, a FanLinc module is wired, much the same way you'd do with any other fan remote receiver; this gives you full dimming control over the connected lights, as well as multi-speed control of the fan.  You can also replace the existing wallbox dimmer with an Insteon dimmer and make all the lights in the room "talk", allowing for one-button scene control of both light sets from the same keypad that handles the fan.  Of course, all the Insteon gear is properly listed and labeled -- Insteon was in the "smart" game well before all the consumer-gadget vendors jumped on the bandwagon.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Looks very interesting. I mean, leaving aside the application, honestly all I really wanted was two switches in one gang, which really isn't THAT complex. But the Insteon products do look very cool and I will check them out for sure.